# Running process in background

Tags: bash, video, background-process, youtube-dl

```
for i in `cat input`
    do
    youtube-dl $i &&
done
```

Here input file contains a list of YouTube video links. I expected this code to do a parallel download of the videos from the list. But the job was completed one after the other. Is it a problem with the code?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `&`, so :

```
for i in $(< input); do
    youtube-dl "$i" &
done
```

### To go further

- the `&&` operator is used in boolean tests, like : `((1 == 1)) && echo "1 == 1" || echo "1 != 1"`
- always protect your variables with double quotes to prevent *bash word splitting* !
- the backticks are deprecated in 2013 in favor of the `$( )` form. It's more readable, and easy to nest.

Comment: Could you be so kind to provide a link about **` `** deprecation? I remember that people stopped using backticks long time before 2013, but I am interested in the official status

Answer (score 1):

Use the `&` symbol instead of the `&&` to run a process in the background. The script should look like this:

```
while read -r i
do
    youtube-dl "$i" &
done < "input"
wait ## Optional if you want the script to wait for all videos to download before exiting
```

Comment: This answer is better than others because it will work correctly with links that contain space characters. But this is going to work only if your links are separated by newline characters.

Comment: Though it may be better to use ``xargs``

Comment: I agree. Limiting the number of parallel processes may be useful if the internet speed is slow, or if the number of connections is too large.

Comment: Actually I meant of putting only one "&". It was  a mistake sry.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `cat input`; do
    youtube-dl "$i" &
done
```

Also, if you don't want to spam youtube with too many simultaneous downloads, you can use this:

```
cat file.txt | xargs -d '\n' -L 1 -P 5 youtube-dl
```

This code will be downloading only 5 videos at the same time. I am pretty sure that it is exactly what you're trying to do. This code will also work for links that contain spaces.

Comment: Yes I was trying to do the same. Is there any other gnu tools which I could use for running jobs in parallel??